# Server side processing in spring restful for angular datatable

Tags: angularjs, spring, restful-url

I have a list of students table which may contain more than ten thousand records.
Is there any tutorial where i can learn angular datatable with spring restful api to load data ,like 10 at a time while using pagination and search option

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I have no idea how to start with it , i have a table with search button and pagination how to achieve lazy loading at server side?

Comment: I just types 'angular datatable rest' in to Google and got plenty of results.  I suggest you do the same.

Comment: i have already gone through it but server side code was not there [link](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side) and they are using jquery inside angular is that ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont understand what you really meant, but you can go to this [link](http://draptik.github.io/blog/2013/07/28/restful-crud-with-angularjs/)
it have angular code and server side java code for processing large data,

hope this helps!